# Date strings as the ids in json-api

Tags: json-api

I'd like to find out is it correct according to json-api standards. I'd like to have item like calendar_day at the top level. Is it correct that data would contain items like

`{:data=>[{:id=>"2020-04-15", :type=>:calendar_day, :attributes=>{:date=>"2020-04-15"}} ...`

and than some relationships for each calendar_day item.

Worth to mention that calendar_day is not actually the "real" record in my db, it's just the app concept although I'v got a model defined to make json-api serializer work with it easy.

Answer (score 1):

Even though there isn't a standard format for dates in json api specification, [ISO 8601 is recommended](https://jsonapi.org/recommendations/#date-and-time-fields). As far as that goes, your example is fine.

All `id` keys [must have](https://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-object-identification) string values.

Having said that, you have to be careful since datestrings aren't unique by themselves. You could use a timestamp just to be sure that you have the right document. With that, you can get any date info that you need down to the millisecond.